# How to use the & operator in C#? Is the the translation of the code correct?

Tags: c#, operators, bitwise-operators, conditional-statements

the line "if(arg2 & 1)" in C++(arg2 is DWORD) is equal to "if(arg2 & 1==0)" in C#(arg2 is Uint32),right?

I am trying to translate a function from C++ to C#,but I get an error:

```
Operator '&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'uint' and 'bool'
```

I'd be also thankful if you could see further in the whole function for any other mistakes.

C++

```
DWORD Func_X_4(DWORD arg1, DWORD arg2, DWORD arg3)
{
LARGE_INTEGER result = {1, 0};
LARGE_INTEGER temp1 = {0};
LARGE_INTEGER temp2 = {0};
LARGE_INTEGER temp3 = {0};
LARGE_INTEGER temp4 = {0};
for(int x = 0; x < 32; ++x)
{
    if(arg2 & 1)
    {
        temp1.LowPart = arg3;
        temp1.HighPart = 0;
        temp2.QuadPart = temp1.QuadPart * result.QuadPart;
        temp3.LowPart = arg1;
        temp3.HighPart = 0;
        temp4.QuadPart = temp2.QuadPart % temp3.QuadPart;
        result.QuadPart = temp4.QuadPart;
    }
    arg2 >>= 1;
    temp1.LowPart = arg3;
    temp1.HighPart = 0;
    temp1.QuadPart *= temp1.QuadPart;
    temp2.LowPart = arg1;
    temp2.HighPart = 0;
    temp3.QuadPart = temp1.QuadPart % temp2.QuadPart;
    arg3 = temp3.LowPart;
    if(!arg2)
        break;
}
return result.LowPart;
}
```

Converted to C#

LARGE_INTEGER structure:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 8)]
public struct LARGE_INTEGER
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public Int64 QuadPart;
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public UInt32 LowPart;
    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public Int32 HighPart;
}
```

Function:

```
public static UInt32 X4(UInt32 arg1, UInt32 arg2, UInt32 arg3)
    {
        LARGE_INTEGER result = new LARGE_INTEGER();
        result.LowPart = 1;
        result.HighPart = 0;
        LARGE_INTEGER temp1 = new LARGE_INTEGER();
        LARGE_INTEGER temp2 = new LARGE_INTEGER();
        LARGE_INTEGER temp3 = new LARGE_INTEGER();
        LARGE_INTEGER temp4 = new LARGE_INTEGER();
        for (int x = 0; x < 32; ++x)
        {
            if (arg1 & 1 ==0)
            {
                temp1.LowPart = arg3;
                temp1.HighPart = 0;
                temp2.QuadPart = temp1.QuadPart * result.QuadPart;
                temp3.LowPart = arg1;
                temp3.HighPart = 0;
                temp4.QuadPart = temp2.QuadPart % temp3.QuadPart;
                result.QuadPart = temp4.QuadPart;
            }
            arg2 >>= 1;
            temp1.LowPart = arg3;
            temp1.HighPart = 0;
            temp1.QuadPart *= temp1.QuadPart;
            temp2.LowPart = arg1;
            temp2.HighPart = 0;
            temp3.QuadPart = temp1.QuadPart % temp2.QuadPart;
            arg3 = temp3.LowPart;
            if (arg2==0)
                break;
        }
        return result.LowPart;
    }
```

This is what I'm not sure yet:

1. Whether a DWORD in C++ is UInt32 or Int32 in C#?
2. if(integer & integer) means if(integer and integer ==0)? //this is where the error i described above is placed.
3. if(!integer) means if(integer != 0)?
4. Why operator & cannot be used logically in C# ,meaning it requires a boolean?
5. "LARGE_INTEGER result = {1, 0}" means result.lowpart is 1 and result.highpart is 0 or result.Quadpart = 1?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Where you write :

if (arg1 & arg2==0)

The compiler understands :

```
if (arg1 & (arg2==0))
```

You should write :

```
if ((arg1 & arg2) == 0)
```

This is the way the C++ statement should be translated to C# :

```
if (arg2 & 1) // C++ (arg2 is DWORD)
if ((arg2 & 1) != 0) // C# (arg2 is Uint32)
```

Or, in a more generic way:

```
if (Flags & FlagToCheck) // C++
if ((Flags & FlagToCheck) != 0) // C#
```

---

In C/C++, 0 is false, everything else is true.

1. You should check the definition of DWORD, it should be (unsigned int), which is UInt32 in C#
2. if (integer & integer), in C/C++ means "if the result of the bitwise and between the two integers is not 0" (0 is false, everything else is true).
3. if (!integer) means if (integer == 0) (again, 0 is false, everything else is true)
4. in C#, like in Java I think, booleans and numbers are two different things, you can only use booleans in "if" statements, there is not implicit conversion if you use an int : it won't compile.
5. I'll leave this one to someone else, I'd need to test to be sure...

Comment: Are you sure its

 if((arg2 & 1) == 1)

Shouldn't it be if((arg2 & 1)==0)?

Could you please check the five things i told i'm wondering about(they are below the two functions).

Thank you,I digged up your answer,will accept it if you confirm the five things. :)

Comment: re "arg2 & 1" => "(arg2 & 1) == 1"; Is that right? I thought C/C++ "true" was "non-zero"; so should be "(arg2 & 1) != 0" - otherwise you are switching "any of" to "all of" ; Ditto: (Flags & FlagToCheck) != 0

Comment: But (arg2 & 1) can only be 1 or 0.  So it works out to the same thing.

Comment: @Jim - ah, right. True, but just *asking* for somebody to fall into a copy/paste trap...

Comment: @Marc: yeah.  "!= 0" is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

1. `DWORD` is `uint32_t` in C++, thus `UInt32` in C#.
2. `if(a & b)` converts to `if((a & b) != 0)`.  `!=` is evaluated before `&` thus the `&` expression needs parentheses around it.
3. `if(x)` converts to `if(x != 0)`
4. `&` is a 'bitwise and' in C#, like in C++.
5. Depends on your C++ structure.

Comment: There's no structure in C++,LARGE_INTEGER is a build it structure.I couldn't find it.

Comment: @John, Then I have no idea.  Look in your header files for LARGE_INTEGER; I doubt it's built into the compiler.

Comment: I figured it out,Low part is first and High part is second,meaning lowpart=1 and highpart=0.
Thanks,I accepted your answer!

Comment: You'll find information about LARGE_INTEGER here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383713(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

5 - It means both.  Because LowPart and HighPart are just "windows" into QuadPart's memory, when result.LowPart == 1 and Result.HighPart == 0, then result.QuadPart will be equal to 1.

Comment: I digged your answer aswell,i figured out how LARGE_INTEGERS work already,but I appreciate that you helped,so +1 :)