# Bitwise '&' operator on uint

Tags: c#, casting, hex

I need to perform a bitwise '&' operation on a value of type `uint`.

```
enum MsgType : ulong
{
Begin = 0x00000001,
}

unit number= 0x00000002;

if (number & MsgType.Begin == MsgType.Begin)
```

//Not working

It is giving an error:

```
Operator '&' cannot be applied on operands of type 'uint' or 'bool'
```

How to cast it?

Comment: which language or platform is this?

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11086333/operator-cannot-be-applied-to-type-ulong-and-int

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/685436/how-to-use-the-operator-in-c-is-the-the-translation-of-the-code-correct

Comment: The language used is C#.

Comment: It isn't clear what is supposed to be tested here.  Maybe (number != 0).

Answer (score 1):

it seems it is an issue of [operator precedence in C#](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_operators_precedence.htm), use parentheses to produce the correct compiler output

i.e instead of this:

`if (number & MsgType.Begin == MsgType.Begin)`

do this:

`if ((number & MsgType.Begin) == MsgType.Begin)`

as per [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/685436/how-to-use-the-operator-in-c-is-the-the-translation-of-the-code-correct)